# How does a connection of a wire to a bus bar work without overheating?

Tags: power, connector

The typical design of a bus bar used in a house main panel is like this:

[image]

a solid bar of brass or copper has two sets of holes - wires are inserted in holes without threading and screws are driven into holes with threading and those holes are perpendicular to each other and so when a screw is driven in it presses the wire to the opposite side of the hole without threading and that secures the wire.

What bothers me is the following. A wire is typically round and a hole is typically round and typically the wire has smaller diameter that the hole. So when a small cylinder of the wire is pressed onto a bigger cylinder of the hole

[image]

the area of contact between them is not very large. Yet this setup is widely used.

How do such connections that presumably provide a very small area of contact conduct up to dozens amperes of current without overheating?

Comment: Usually the wires used in this way are made out of more small twisted wires, so the surface is increased, also because of the deformation of copper. And AFAIK the screw is conductive too.

Comment: @clabacchio: The most typical setup I've seen is when the wire is solid, not stranded. This is why I ask.

Comment: Ok :) can you post a photo?

Comment: @clabacchio: Not to infridge copyright here're Google search for pics results - almost any setup uses solid wires http://www.google.ru/search?q=connect+wire+to+a+bus+bar+photo&hl=ru&newwindow=1&prmd=imvns&source=lnms&tbm=isch&ei=rq5UT_yVH87Esgbw__SODA&sa=X&oi=mode_link&ct=mode&cd=2&ved=0CCAQ_AUoAQ&biw=1280&bih=839#hl=ru&newwindow=1&tbm=isch&sa=1&q=connect+wire+to+a+neutral+bus+bar+photo&pbx=1&oq=connect+wire+to+a+neutral+bus+bar+photo&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&gs_sm=3

Comment: There are bothe stranded and solid conductors shown in those pictures. The New Zealand regulations require such wire to be multi-stranded. However, solid copper will deform "quite happily" under screw pressure.

Comment: In the US, all permanently mounted house wiring I've ever seen at #10 size and smaller was single strand.  That also makes sense to me since the main advantage of multi-strand is it has longer life under repeated flexing.  The other advantage, in some cases depending on exactly how the strands are arranged and insulated, is that it can carry high frequencies better due to the skin effect.  Neither of these advantages matter in a fixed installation at 60 Hz at #10 and smaller.  I have seen #8 stranded, but that was because it would be too difficult to install otherwise (it was still a pain).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't agree that the contact area is all that small.  Copper is fairly maleable, so will deform somewhat when the screw is tightened.  That will make it fit the shape of the hole for a little ways at the bottom, and the bottom of the screw at the top.  Keep in mind the bottom deformation will be a bit longer than the diameter of the screw at least.

If you add up all the contact area, it should exceed the cross section area of the wire.  It's probably at least twice that actually.  If the connection is made properly, then it is gas-tight and should be effectively continuous copper.  As long as it is equivalent to the solid copper of the wire diameter, it will dissipate no more power than the wire itself for the same length.  Even if it dissipates a little more, the bar is capable of dissipating far more heat than the wire with insulation cover.

You could come from it the other way and do the math.  The largest typical house currents are 30 A, which requires #10 cable legally, at least here in the US.  A copper bar like that should be able to get rid of 1 W of heat per junction point without any temperature rise that matters.  The resistance to dissipate 1 W at 30 A is 1.1 mΩ.  That would be a surprisingly high resistance for such a joint with a #10 cable.

If you really want to know, test it.  Get a bar, some copper cable, and test the resistance.  It will be so low that you will need to do 4-wire measurement at decent current like a few Amps, but it should be doable.